# I have a problem regarding showing images from firebase in Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I want to show my uploaded images from firebase storage in a Recyclerview.

Here is my ImagesShowingNotices.java class

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ImageAdapter mAdapter;

private ProgressBar mProgressCircle;

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private List<Uplaodfiles> mUploads;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_showing_notices);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewitems);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mProgressCircle = findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);

    mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Uploads");

    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Uplaodfiles upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Uplaodfiles.class);
                mUploads.add(upload);
            }

            mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImageShowingNotices.this, mUploads);

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ImageShowingNotices.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}
```

Here is my UploadFiles.java class

```
public Uplaodfiles() {
    //empty constructor needed
}

public Uplaodfiles(String name, String imageUrl) {
    if (name.trim().equals("")) {
        name = "No Name";
    }

    mName = name;
    mImageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getName() {
    return mName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    mName = name;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return mImageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    mImageUrl = imageUrl;
}
```

Here is my ImageAdpter.java class

```
@Override
public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_items, parent, false);
    return new ImageViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Uplaodfiles uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
    holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
            .into(holder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mUploads.size();
}

public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textViewName;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);
    }
}
```

Logcat shows, " No adapter attached; skipping layout".
I have tried other solutions regarding this problem posted on StackOverflow, but nothing worked for me. Please help me to get me out of this situation.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Your question is primarily code-based, try to provide `stacktrace`

Comment: I see an accepted answer. Have you solved the problem? If not, add the database structure as requested. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Hii, here is my rule: service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post database structure image
You may be reference wrong node

Comment: Ok i will post the database structure image

Answer (score 0):

I think **onDataChanged** method in your callback is not called correctly.

Check your realtime database node structure and Check logcat **warn** level for firebase realtimedatabase warnning.

Maybe access rule or any other problem can cause your IO fail.

Also, Recreation of **Adapter** when the data is changed is not a good solution.

Set your adapter to RecyclerView at first of lifecycle once.

And you can just change the datas of Adapter and call **notifyDatasetChanged** using Adapter.

Test first your RecyclerView first with dummy datas.

Comment: I did the adapter setting at first recyclerview but app crashed